# Почему нет тире между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Книга всегда лучший подарок.*

Почему в этом предложении нет тире между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Answer (score 5):

*Книга **всегда** лучший подарок.*

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91) (справочник Розенталя):

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:
> <...>
> **4)** если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, иногда — наречие, союз, частица: *Дубава, **кажется**, друг Корчагина* (Н. О); *Риск, **как известно**, дело благородное; Необдуманный поступок **вообще** шаг опасный; Сергеев **теперь** известный художник; Пихта **тоже** дерево смолистое; Март **только** начало весны.*

**P. S.**  При логическом и интонационном подчеркивании тире возможно:
*Кн**И**га – всегда лучший подарок.*
*Книга всегд**А** – лучший подарок.*

Answer (score 0):

**О ПРАВИЛАХ**

В данной теме при выборе **тире** особенно важно **произношение**, так как учитываются не только правила, но и расстановка **логических ударений и пауз.**

**[ПАС под ред.Лопатина](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478667/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC)**

§ 10. Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей **связки** ставится тире, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа: **Примечание.** Тире может **не ставиться,** если в письменной речи отражено произношение с логическим ударением на **сказуемом**: *Моя сестра учительница* (ср.: *Моя сестра — учительница* — ударение **и на слове сестра, и на слове учительница**).

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

(1) *Я решил подарить другу книгу. **Книга всегда / лучший подАрок.***

При наличии наречия ***"всегда"*** тире не ставится. **Как это объяснить (кроме правил)?**

Здесь интонация **простого** предложения: оно делится на две фонетические фразы (части), а пауза **произносительная.**  Ударение в конце первой фразы тоническое (**незначительное** повышение тона перед паузой). Фактически же оно уходит **на конец предложения.**  (Считается, что здесь **одно ударение**.) Интонация **ровная**, логических ударений и увеличенных пауз нет.

(2) Можно поставить **тире,** если выделить **логическим**  ударением слово ***"книга":***

*Не знаете, что подарить другу? Тогда подарите ему книгу. **КнИга — всегда лучший подАрок**.*

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.**  А вот произносительный вариант **"Книга всегдА — лучший подарок"** вызывает сомнение. Тоническое ударение можно при желании заменить **логическим (силовым),** но тогда **тире** не надо ставить (нет произношения с увеличенной паузой).